# Windows service not triggering scheduled task

Tags: c#, service

I have an XML file which contains scheduling dates. I want to create a service that will read the date and time from the XML file and trigger (call my application) on that time.

I tried a lot but the service doesn't not trigger my application so I made a console application to replicate my service which work perfectly.

Also, on my service, on `Start`/`Stop` I am creating a log file which does seem to be working it just appears to be my trigger that doesn't.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    TraceService("start service");
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
    timer.Interval = 60000;
    timer.Enabled = true;
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    timer.Enabled = false;
    TraceService("stopping service");
}

private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    TraceService(" Varun Another entry at " + DateTime.Now);
}

private void TraceService(string content)
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"d:\Varun-Pc start up.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
    sw.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
    sw.WriteLine(content);
    sw.Flush();
    sw.Close();
    connect();
    string xmldata = "";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Schedualer_Master", cn);
    DataSet mds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(mds);
    for (int i = 0; i < mds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        xmldata = "";
        xmldata = mds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["XML_Data"].ToString();
        TaskScheduler.TriggerItem newItem = TaskScheduler.TriggerItem.FromXML(xmldata);
        newItem.Enabled = true; 
        _taskScheduler.AddTrigger(newItem); // set item into trigger
        _taskScheduler.Enabled = true;
    }
    object sender = new object();
    EventArgs e = new EventArgs();
    _taskScheduler._triggerTimer_Tick(sender, e);
}
```

And this is my trigger function

```
public void _triggerTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _triggerTimer.Stop();
    foreach (TriggerItem item in TriggerItems)
    if (item.Enabled)
    {
        while (item.TriggerTime <= DateTime.Now)
        {
            item.RunCheck(DateTime.Now);
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("E:\\SqlBackup_Programs\\console-backup\\Backup_Console_App 22July Latest\\Backup_Console_App\\Backup_Console_App\\bin\\Debug\\Backup_Console_App");
        }
    }
    _triggerTimer.Start();
}
```

Comment: For one thing, you are not starting anything because you don't specify a process to be started, you just provided a path to it, maybe.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek using this same coding I make one console as well as windows application which runs perfectly,

Comment: This doesn't make sense, if you have a *fixed* list of date/times why not just manually setup the task scheduler to call your app? What is the webservice actually giving you here?

Comment: @james on professional level we can't suggest our client to use windows task schedualer, so i make my own which will automatic take back up of my database according my XML FILE

Comment: @VARUNNAYAK it's very rare you see a windows service setup something in the task scheduler - generally you opt for one over the other. If you need a backup to run at set intervals why not just have your service trigger the application directly? The scheduler setup seems like an unnecessary step.

Comment: @James here TaskScheduler is my class not external setup,
In this class i set variables according to XML FILE,